# Numpy - combining 2d arrays with a 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My use case is causing me to struggle with numpy append and concatenate. I wanted to reach out to determine if there is a clean way of handling the following challenge.

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
b = [10, 11, 12]
```

I would like to combine so that they look like this:

```
c = [[1, 2, 3, 10],
     [4, 5, 6, 11],
     [7, 8, 9, 12]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way is `np.c_` which handles 1D arrays intelligently:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],                                                                                                                                       
     [4, 5, 6],                                                                                                                                       
     [7, 8, 9]]
b = [10, 11, 12]
 
np.c_[a,b]
# array([[ 1,  2,  3, 10],
#        [ 4,  5,  6, 11],
#        [ 7,  8,  9, 12]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I had not come across np.c_ before, and when I ran it on the dataset it was extremely fast. very clean as well. I am very impressed. Out of the responses that I have received, each were valid and met the requirement, but this one was the most elegant and performs very well.  Thank you all for helping me to solve this! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla python you can do a list comprehension with zip:

```
out = [u+[v] for u,v in zip(a,b)]
# [[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6, 11], [7, 8, 9, 12]]
```

But since you tagged `numpy`, you can use `hstack` like this:

```
np.hstack((a,np.array([b]).T))
```

---

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3, 10],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 11],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 12]])
```

Comment: This works well! As the data is already a numpy array, my prefererence is to maintain the array rather than converting it. Your hstack solution works well, and you have taught me how this type of problem can be addressed with zip as well. I prefer to minimize for loops where possible so the hstack works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [10,11,12]
for k in range(len(a)):
    a[k].append(b[k])
```

I'm not entirely sure this would work in any case but it works for that example at least. This doesn't use Numpy though, it works on Python list as well.

Comment: Thank you, this works and is a viable solution. I appreciate your response. I do try to avoid for loops, and the dataset is quite large so my preference is to stay within numpy. clever solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, since you mentioned `numpy` and `concatenate`,
here is the way to do it using them:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
b = np.array([10, 11, 12])

print(np.concatenate((a, b.reshape((-1, 1))), axis=1))
```

```
[[ 1  2  3 10]
 [ 4  5  6 11]
 [ 7  8  9 12]]
```

Comment: I was not reshaping the data before feeding it into np.concatenate so I now know where I was going wrong. Thank you!